# How to point multiple domains to single site?

Tags: dns, hosting

I have hosting with `godaddy` and 6 domains registered like `mysite.com, mysite.org etc.` with domains.upperlink.ng

I set godaddy nameserver for mysite.com and it works fine. Now how to set other domains? I also want other domains to redirect to .com domain.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: do you have access to your http.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support. 
But I got solution.

1) I added nameserver to all domains.
2) I create parked domains in godaddy where it is hosted.
3) I added redirects in parked domains to main domain.

This way my task is done.